# Bootstrap 4 Datepicker CSS broken with Angular 6

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular6, ng-bootstrap

bootstrap in my whole project but the Datepicker is broken.

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" ]
```

Im using:

Angular: 6.0.1

Angular-CLI: 6.0.1

Bootstrap: 4.1.1

ng-bootstrap: 2.2.0

[broken Datepicker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKlI3.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need to provide more elements for us to help you with your issue. For instance, the HTML you wrote in your angular template.

Comment: ng-bootstrap is tested with Bootstrap 4.0.0 (I don't know the changes form Bootstrap 4.0.0 to Bootstrap 4.1.1

Comment: Can't reproduce, works for me here with Bootstrap 4.1.1: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wb7j3m?file=index.html